# How binding a Item property of Observable Collection to Switch status?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have a collection of Social Media in an ObservableCollectionRange that I initialize as follows:

```
public ObservableRangeCollection<SocialMediaEntity> CurrentSocialMedia { get; } = new ObservableRangeCollection<SocialMediaEntity>();
```

Below I obtain this list of a web service and I keep these elements in the collection:

```
GetSonInformation().Subscribe((SonInformation) =>
                {
                    CurrentSon = SonInformation.Son;
                    CurrentSocialMedia.ReplaceRange(SonInformation.SocialMedia);

                });
```

On the page I have a Switch component that I want to be enabled if the token is valid and is not valid if the token is invalid or there is no such social medium in the collection.

```
    <Switch Grid.Column="1" 
      VerticalOptions="Center"
    HorizontalOptions="End" 
   IsToggled="{Binding Path=CurrentSocialMedia,  
     Converter={StaticResource SocialMediaStatusToBoolConverter},
    ConverterParameter={StaticResource youtubeKey}}">

     <Switch.Behaviors>
       <behaviors:EventHandlerBehavior EventName="Toggled">
           <behaviors:InvokeCommandAction
                Command="{Binding ToggleYoutubeSocialMediaCommand}"
                 Converter="{StaticResource SwitchChangeEventArgsConverter}"/>

                                                    </behaviors:EventHandlerBehavior>

                                            </Switch.Behaviors>
                                        </Switch>
```

The approach I've followed is to link the collection and use a converter that returns a Boolean value with the logic I mentioned earlier.

```
public class SocialMediaStatusToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {

            IList<SocialMediaEntity> SocialMedias = (IList<SocialMediaEntity>)value;

            if (SocialMedias == null || SocialMedias.Count() == 0)
                return false;

            var socialMedia = SocialMedias.SingleOrDefault(social => social.Type.Equals((string)parameter));

            return socialMedia != null && !socialMedia.InvalidToken;
        }


        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that this is only done the first time. When I update the collection by replacing all items or adding another, nothing is updated.

Can anyone tell me what approach I should take to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Switch` is not expecting a collection for `IsToggled` property, it won't monitor collection changed events on the bound data. Not like **[a `Picker` would do for `ItemsSource`.](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Picker.cs#L123)**

So the onus comes back to the view-model. Basically, the viewmodel needs to ensure that the property-changed-event for `CurrentSocialMedia` is raised every time the collection is changed.

**For e.g:**

```
void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{ 
    if(args.PropertyName != nameof(CurrentSocialMedia))
        return;

    var oldObservable = oldValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
    if (oldObservable != null)
        oldObservable.CollectionChanged -= CollectionChanged;

    var newObservable = newValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
    if (newObservable != null) {
        newObservable.CollectionChanged += CollectionChanged;
    }
}

void CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentSocialMedia));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged to your SocialMediaEntity